# Put class instance (Pimage) in arraylist (NullPointer exception)

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

In my Processing application, I need to use multiple images to render UI. Now I can of course make tons of variables like `img1`, `img2`, `img3` and so on...
But I rather tried this:

```
ArrayList<PImage> images;

void setup() {

   sendMessageCode((byte)0, (byte)1);
   //Loading images and fonts
   images.add(loadImage("hi-tech-clock_transparent.png"));  //Null pointer exception!
   images.add(loadImage("button.png"));
}
```

Problem is, that this aproach, valid in normal, non-java languages, throws Null Pointer exception. Almost seems like I used some pointers. But there is no pointering with class instance as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to initialize your `images`. Add the below code snippet before adding the images to the list.

```
images = new ArrayList<PImage>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your `List`:

```
List<PImage> images = new ArrayList<PImage>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not assigned object for images

```
ArrayList<PImage> images = new ArrayList<PImage>();
```

You are getting `NullPointerException` because you are calling a method on the object reference which has not been assigned any object.